# Session not retaining value after every page refresh

Tags: php, session, php-5.6

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
if(empty($_SESSION['a'])) {
    $_SESSION['a'] = mt_rand();
}

print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

The code is placed on page1.php and after every page refresh the variable 'a' value is being set again and again. Whats the problem with the above code?

Comment: It's working on local but not on live.

Comment: how are the php ini settings file of your production project?

Comment: You have to use isset() than empty().

Comment: why? @shashikant there's nothing wrong with `empty`!

Comment: @shashikant the above code is working fine on local with empty and also working with !isset.

Comment: In which server you have try this code ?

Comment: @Jalpa Its on rackspace.

Comment: @яша other websites are running with the same ini settings and with the above code and working well.

Comment: @SURFER-TM I think in live some where you have put blank line or HTML code that's way you code not working in live.

Comment: !isset($_SESSION['a']) && empty($_SESSION['a']); or try 
array_key_exists('a',$_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION['a']) Please refer this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519818/how-do-check-if-a-php-session-is-empty

Comment: is session_start() called in all the pages?

Comment: @Jalpa I have just upload one page on the live server for testing no online  3 lines of code. So no point of whitespace :-)

Comment: @яша Yes the above code is included in all the pages. But for the sake of testing I have created an empty php page with just the above code in it and its not working. So what's the problem with it?

Comment: what is print_r($_SESSION) outputting?

Comment: @яша Array ( ) Array ( [a] => 1902502826 )

Comment: add this to your code phpinfo(); and see the session.save_path variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102245/discussion-between--and-surfer-tm).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the php file encoding system. I opened the php file in latest notepad++ version and checked the "Encoding" and it was UTF-8 with BOM and I changed it to just UTF-8. And wolla it worked like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue of Encoding. Please open your file on notepad++ new version and set file into Encoding in UTF-8. I hope your issue will be fix :)

Answer (score -1):

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11569930/2229572).

It says that you need to set proper read/write privileges to the  php/webserver process' user.

Make sure that the `/var/lib/session/` directory is readable/writable for `www-data`.